# Cocoa: make url data request, run local DOM-altering javascript, store modified html

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsurlconnection

Let's say I have some data from a webpage:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myurl]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSData* returnedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
NSString* html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I also have a local javascript script that runs some queries on the data and modifies the DOM. At the moment, in order to achieve this, I am taking the HTML received above, creating a webview and loading this into it:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<script>%@</script>%@", myscript, html];
```

I am then, on the webview didFinishLoadForFrame event, calling

```
NSString* modifiedhtml = [sender stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"]]
```

This leaves me with my modifiedhtml, with which I can do as I please. However- this doesn't seem elegant at all, especially since creating webviews is only permitted on the main thread and this whole process would ideally run in a background thread, also, very occasionally the script throws an error and the webview load event is not called so I have a growing number of lines just dedicated to handling a timeout for this occurrence. It is, all in all, a big ugly mess.

In an ideal world I would apply this javascript on the first pass without creating a webview at all. I've been trying all sorts of things like:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myurl]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSData* returnedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
NSString* html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* modifiedhtml = [request stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: myscript]];
```

where the script is set to return the page but to no avail.

Are there any suggestions as how to handle this more elegantly and efficiently than I am currently?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you want to achieve: if the problem is to send a request in background then send it asynchronously, using the NSURLConnectionDelagate method connection:didReceiveData: to concatenate the response data and connectionDidFinishLoading: to modify the html received and to create and load the webView.

Comment: @MichelePercich When you say use "connectionDidFinishLoading: to modify the html received", I would like to make these modifications using javascript, and so I need a way to process the javascript and apply it to the the html received.

Comment: You've written that you already have a solution for this "This leaves me with my modified html, with which I can do as I please.". So, what you need more?

Comment: Yes, it is fine for my needs - this question is purely academic - and the question is really - is this the most efficient and elegant way to render some javascript, and is there a solution that does not require using the main thread (as webview creation does).

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the use of a web view and assuming that your html has a `head` tag you could do something like this:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [html componentsSeparatedByString:@"<head>"];
NSString *modifiedHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<head>%@%@", [tempArray objectAtIndex:0], yourScriptString, [tempArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

It will insert your script into the existing `head` tag. You should complete the code with usual sanity checks.